# timeago jquery plugin doesn't work with some dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have timeago jquery plugin, and doesn't work with this element date:

```
<span title="Tue, 28 Jun 2011 19:19:31 GMT" class="time-ago">Tue, 28 Jun 2011 19:19:31 GMT</span>
```

Also not working with this:

```
<span title="Tue, 21 Jun 2011 22:53:07 GMT" class="time-ago">Tue, 21 Jun 2011 22:53:07 GMT</span>
```

======================================================

and in the same time it works fine with this:

```
<span title="Wed, 29 Jun 2011 23:10:34 GMT" class="time-ago">Wed, 29 Jun 2011 23:10:34 GMT</span>
```

And this:

```
<span title="Sat, 25 Jun 2011 20:31:42 GMT" class="time-ago">Sat, 25 Jun 2011 20:31:42 GMT</span>
```

can't get where is the problem, both dates are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by saving dates in the db by UTC, and then while rendering I attache to it a Z char.
So it will be something like this `<span class="time-ago">@MyDate.ToString()Z</span>`

Comment: Adding the Z in c# fixed it for me too: <span title='@item.CreatedOn.ToString("o")Z' >

Answer (score 0):

Author of jquery-timeago here.

[As the docs reference](http://timeago.yarp.com/), an [ISO 8601](http://timeago.yarp.com/) timestamp is required for everything to work as expected in timeago:

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</time>
```